# Copy Multiple table to postgres database using shell script

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgresql-copy

I have two databases one in mysql and other in postgres.

I want to copy nearly ten table data to postgres database which already has tables with the same name.

I want to do this using a shell script because i don't want do write 10 individual command to copy those tables.

How to achieve this?

Comment: In _Postgres_: From where you want to copy data(_from an external file like csv or another Postgres DB_) ?? and I guess that table has same name as well as same data type also

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: From another mysql database. Yes it has same datatypes.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you have tried, and what is the error / issue you are experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to make mysqldump with `--compatible=postgresql` flag of required tables, and than insert them into your postgres database.